# Missing icons in my opencart shop

Tags: image, .htaccess, icons, opencart

I am using opencart v1.5.6.4 with vqmods installed. In my home page I am not seeing the icons. I was wondering if someone has seen this before?

Screenshots: [biopatikus.hu/01.png](https://biopatikus.hu/01.png)    [biopatikus.hu/02.png](https://biopatikus.hu/02.png)

(If I use the https://, the icons are appear)

This is my .htacces file:

```html
# STARTNITRO
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE:%{HTTP:If-Modified-Since}]
ExpiresActive On

#CSS JS XML TXT - 1 WEEK
<FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt|css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 week"
</FilesMatch>

#JPG JPEG PNG GIF SWF SVG - 1 MONTH
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|svg|JPG|JPEG|PNG|GIF|SWF|SVG)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, public"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
Header set Last-Modified "Wed, 05 Jun 2009 06:40:46 GMT"
</FilesMatch>

#OTF WOFF TTF ICO PDF FLV - 1 MONTH
<FilesMatch "\.(otf|ico|pdf|flv|woff|ttf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, public"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</FilesMatch>
# ENDNITRO
# STARTCOMPRESSNITRO

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\/?((catalog)|(assets)).+)\.css$ assets/style.php?l=4&p=$1&c=604800 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\/?((catalog)|(assets)).+)\.js$ assets/script.php?l=4&p=$1&c=604800 [NC,L]
# ENDCOMPRESSNITRO










RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.biopatikus\.hu$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/biopatikus\.hu\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]


# Force no caching for dynamic files
<FilesMatch "\.(php|cgi|pl|htm)$">
ExpiresActive Off
Header set Cache-Control "private, no-cache, no-store, proxy-revalidate, no-transform"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
</FilesMatch>

# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 

# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]



### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
# php_flag register_globals off

# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value post_max_size 999M

# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_execution_time 200

# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_input_time 200

# 7. disable open_basedir limitations
# php_admin_value open_basedir none
```

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer this link : http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=21166

Users having issue with https , images not showing on https pages. So as a solution you can try opposite trick they have done.

Check your config.php file for the values of **HTTP_SERVER** and **HTTPS_SERVER** constants. Make sure that you have correct values set.

Comment: Thank you!:) I edited the config.php. My HTTP link was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
// HTTP
define(‘HTTP_SERVER’, ‘https://www.blazingcoders.com‘);

// HTTPS
define(‘HTTPS_SERVER’, ‘https://www.blazingcoders.com‘);

config.php – OpenCart admin folder
// HTTP
define(‘HTTP_SERVER’, ‘https://www.blazingcoders.com/admin/‘);
define(‘HTTP_CATALOG’, ‘https://www.blazingcoders.com/‘);

// HTTPS
define(‘HTTPS_SERVER’, ‘https://www.blazingcoders.com/admin/‘);
define(‘HTTPS_CATALOG’, ‘https://www.blazingcoders.com/‘);
```

Detail Explanation is given in the below article 
https://www.blazingcoders.com/how-to-fix-opencart-missing-icons-problem